# Series of if's in loop give wrong results in multi-threaded app

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am oversimplifying for the sake of clarity. Hoping someone has come across this kind of weird behavior.

I have two threads that each contain loops going very fast (on the order of once per millisecond), Thread1 one updates a series of a variables using functions, and Thread2 has a series of ifs designed to act on those variable values. I have timed the operations and the speed of execution of the functions inside each loop, and in each case the functions execute and return values faster than the speed of each loop iteration[implemented as a timer thread]). Thread2:

```
public static int A;
public static int B;

public static bool Flag1 = true;

Thread1:
A = func1 (x, y, z)
B = func2 (p, r, q)

Thread2:
if (!A)
{
    Flag1 = true;
}

if ((Flag1==true) && A && foobar1)
{
    Flag1 = false;
    // Do something;
}
```

The really weird behavior is that Flag1 is definitely not behaving correctly. It gets set to true when the variables in the Thread1 do not warrant that. Help!

Comment: I think you've oversimplified the problem.  There's not enough information here to have any idea what's going on.

Comment: Are you performing any locking or otherwise handling the fact that you are mutating state across different threads?

Comment: Your question does not sufficiently describe the details of what each thread is doing.  "Not behaving correctly" doesn't describe what the correct behaviour should be.  Typically it's a good idea to make use of a `lock` statement when accessing shared state.  I don't see evidence of you doing that.  This is also not sufficient code for me to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added more for clarification

Comment: "not behaving correctly" means the Flag1 remains true even when A, B, and that second conditional being hit warrants otherwise. I want a sort of "hooking" behavior where Flag1 will not allow that second clause to execute unless the A and B conditions "reset" it to true....I am definitely not seeing that behavior

Comment: You need to provide more details about where and how those variables are getting updated. (are there locks?) Also, add details about `foobar1` as well.

Comment: foobar1 involves B which is a value calculated from Thread1

Comment: foobar1 is a conditional involving B, which is an integer declared as a static public variable so that it can be accessed by Thread1 which constantly modifies it via a function

Comment: Thread2 need to read `A` into a local variable to ensure the value isn't changed between if tests. Note that you only need a lock on that read, if what you are reading is larger than a machine word. If you need to read a consistent set of values for both A and B, you will need to lock around writing and reading *both* values.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! This looks super promising!

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be made more clear.

Changed "A" in "Thread1"
If "Thread2" is intended to monitor
First we need to make sure that the "A" value is coming correctly.

Write log for "A" on "Thread1"
It also writes a log for "A" on "Thread2".

These issues are usually caused by inter-thread timing issues.
The best way to check this is with logs.